# Why am I getting this NodeJS installation problem?

Tags: node.js

I am getting this error while installing nodejs 14.7:

[image]

Comment: Are you running it with admin rights?

Comment: yes, my account is an administrator account

Answer (score 0):

Solved it in a very weird way. I had to add a user group called Authenticated Users to windows manually.